# How to export part of a model in Blender as an STL file and keep the original scale

Tags: 3d-printing

I made a model of a character, and I [![want to export it to parts as stl files to 3D print. But when I export some part of character, I found it size change, what should I do?
[image: After export stl files, I put all part together to check size]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192314/export-to-stl-format-in-correct-scale-inches?rq=1